# Retrieving data from JSON file in JS getting an error

Tags: javascript, json

Im getting a Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

```
var mydata = JSON.parse("file.json");
console.log(myJSON)
```

Below is an example of the data in the JSON file.

```
[[1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1],
[1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0],
[1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
[1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0], .... etc]
```

How can I retrieve the data from this JSON file in JS?

Is it not possible to write a JSON like this?

When I open the file in the browser, it looks like a neat JSON array?

[image: browser JSON file]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON.parse` expects an actual JSON string instead of the file name, e.g. `JSON.parse('{ "a": "b" }')`. If you want to do it inside Node.js, you can use `fs` module to read file and parse it. In browser, you need to use file input to read the file first.

Comment: ah oke! When i was using: 

$.getJSON("file.json", function(json) {
    console.log(json); 
}); I was getting a Cross-Origin-aanvraag blocked, so I thought i could also do it like above

Comment: Glad to help :)